# How to plot a bar chart in android?

Tags: android, database, bar-chart, achartengine

I have created a bar chart using achartengine but the values plotted in the graph is static. Now i have created a database using sqlite and i want to draw the bar chart using the values from the database and refresh it every 1 min so that it plots new values if any. I am posting my code below. Please guide me on how to modify the code so that i can do the above. I tried many tutorials online but it didnt help much.

```
package flu.solutions.travelsense;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type;
import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.SimpleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.Orientation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.Menu;
public class ChartActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = createIntent();
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public Intent createIntent() 

     {

    String[] titles = new String[] { "Top 10 Destinations", " " };
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(new double[] { 8, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 9, 5, 7, 8, 8 });
    values.add(new double[] {});

    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.RED, Color.BLACK};

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

    setChartSettings(renderer, "Top 10 Destinations", " ", " ", 0,10, 0,10, Color.GRAY, Color.GREEN);

    renderer.setXLabels(1);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);

    renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Bangalore");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Mysore");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Chennai");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "Delhi");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(5, "Kolkatta");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(6, "Kashmir");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(7, "Hyderabad");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(8, "Mumbai");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(9, "Kerala");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(10, "Gujarat");

    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
      SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
      seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
      }

    return ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) 
    {

    // creates a SeriesRenderer and initializes it with useful default values as well as colors

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(26);

        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);

        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);

        renderer.setLegendTextSize(25);

        int length = colors.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        {
          SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
          r.setColor(colors[i]);
          //r.setChartvalueAngle(-90);
          r.setChartValuesSpacing(15);
          renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        return renderer;
      }

       protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
       String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,int labelsColor) 
      {

      // sets lots of default values for this renderer

       renderer.setChartTitle(title);

       renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
       renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);

       renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
       renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);

       renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
       renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);

       renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
       renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);

       renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
       renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

       renderer.setBarSpacing(1);

    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> values) 
    {

        // adds the axis titles and values into the dataset

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        int length = titles.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        {
          CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
          double[] v = values.get(i);
          int seriesLength = v.length;
          for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
          {
            series.add(v[k]);
          }

          dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
         }
        return dataset;
        }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_chart, menu);
        return true;
    }
      }
```

Comment: Check this [Bar Chart in Android With out any Built in jars](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/bar-chart-in-android-with-out-any-built-in-jars/). Here you can draw charts without any built in jars.

Comment: Hi @Sreekesh i want to upload the values to the bar chart dynamically do you know how to do that??

Comment: @Jayant Try setting value of 'grossSal' and 'netSal' as values from database in form of array or list.

Comment: I tried modifying the above code but it didnt work. I am trying to display the top 10 travel destinations.

Comment: you need to make your chart load as a view (rather than intent) and then refresh it when you want. this should get you in the right direction http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9fozQ5NlSo

Comment: @mango that vedio is to create line graph how do you convert it to bar graph??

Comment: there's no need for converting one graph to another, the principles still apply.

Comment: I know but for my app i need to display it in the form of a bar chart.

Comment: there is no issue here. you literally just replace all the lines that say lineChart with barChart. except for lack of `setBarSpacing()` the procedure is identical

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following: achartengine, AndroidPlot or charts4j. If you want to do it programmatically, then here is a program:

```java
public class BarchartsampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    static XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset;
    static XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer;
    static XYSeriesRenderer rendererSeries;
    static CategorySeries series;
    static GraphicalView mChartView;
    String xvalstring1,xvalstring2,xvalstring3,xvalstring4,xvalstring5;
    int xvalint1,xvalint2,xvalint3,xvalint4,xvalint5;


     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        xvalstring1=intent.getStringExtra("xvalstring1").toString().trim();
        xvalstring2=intent.getStringExtra("xvalstring2").toString().trim();
        xvalstring3=intent.getStringExtra("xvalstring3").toString().trim();
        xvalstring4=intent.getStringExtra("xvalstring4").toString().trim();
        xvalstring5=intent.getStringExtra("xvalstring5").toString().trim();     
        xvalint1=Integer.parseInt(xvalstring1);
        xvalint2=Integer.parseInt(xvalstring2);
        xvalint3=Integer.parseInt(xvalstring3);
        xvalint4=Integer.parseInt(xvalstring4);
        xvalint5=Integer.parseInt(xvalstring5);

     String[] titles = new String[] { "USER INPUTS" };
        List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
        List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        values
                .add(new double[] { xvalint1,xvalint2,xvalint3,xvalint4,xvalint5 });
        dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setChartTitle("USER INPUTS");
        renderer.setXTitle("X");
        renderer.setYTitle("Y");
        renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(10);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(40);
        renderer.setClickEnabled(false);
        renderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(false);
        renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0,5,0,100 });
        renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
        renderer.setShowGrid(true);
        /*renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);*/
        renderer.setBarSpacing(1.5);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 20});
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.GREEN);
        rendererSeries = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        rendererSeries.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        rendererSeries.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererSeries);

      if (mChartView == null) {
            Log.d("Oncreate ", "if (mChartView == null)");
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, mDataset(titles,
                    x, values), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
            layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        } else {
    //              mChartView.repaint();
                Log.d("Oncreate ", "if (mChartView != null)");
        }
    }    
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset(String[] titles,
            List<double[]> xValues, List<double[]> yValues) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset1 = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        addXYSeries(dataset1, titles, xValues, yValues, 0);
        return dataset1;
    }
    private void addXYSeries(XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, String[] titles,
            List<double[]> xValues, List<double[]> yValues, int scale) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int length = titles.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i], scale);
            double[] xV = xValues.get(i);
            double[] yV = yValues.get(i);
            int seriesLength = xV.length;
            for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
                series.add(xV[k], yV[k]);



            }
            dataset.addSeries(series);
        }

    }
}
```