# Intent giving error while working with BarChartExample

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I am following example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795620/how-to-plot-a-bar-chart-in-android)
I am getting following error about `GraphicalActivity`

**Error Log:**

```
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emazdoor.achartdroid/com.emazdoor.achartdroid.ChartActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.emazdoor.achartdroid/org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.emazdoor.achartdroid/org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at com.emazdoor.achartdroid.ChartActivity.onCreate(ChartActivity.java:25)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
05-11 15:51:11.749: E/AndroidRuntime(7353):     ... 11 more
```

Can Anyone here please tell me what is the problem here? I have added the ChartActivity in `AndroidMenifest.xml`too. But the error kept coming back. There is also one error at line

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = createIntent();
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this in your AndroidManifest.Xml :

```
<activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />
```

Comment: thanks @Arash it worked. One question why do I need to add this?

Comment: whenever you are creating a new activity, you should add the activity to the AndroidManifest

Comment: Yes I know that, But I didnt create `GraphicalActivity` :(

Comment: @Ahmed :you are welcome , this Activity is default Activity of AchartEngine to show barcharts.the codes written to it's engine

Comment: Thanks mate that was pretty quick.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't have this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Add to your manifest file:

```
<activity
            android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared the `GraphicalActivity` activity in your AndroidManifest.xml. You have to remember, whenever you are creating a new activity, you should add the activity to the `AndroidManifest` file like this:

```
<activity android:name=".newActivity">
```

Add this:

```
<activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />
```